# MultiThreading Query in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I went for an interview and there i faced one question which is something like this.

```
int RetrieveAmount(String User) Throws UnableToRetrieveAmountException() {
     int amount = 0;
     int amount1 = RetrieveFromSystem1(User);
     int amount2 = RetrieveFromSystem2(User);

     amount = amount1+amount2;

     return amount;

}
```

RetrieveAmount is a syncronozed function

1). Modify the code such that RetrieveFromSystemX(String user) should run independent of each other i.e. if the 1st one is taking 10 seconds and second function also takes 10 second to execute then they should be run in parallel.

2). RetrieveFromSystemX() is taking more time then a time out should happen.

Could anyone give me some pointers on this.

For the first part, I can use the executors with fixed thread pool of number of threads as 2 and can have two separate locks locking each one of these functions. Now two threads can act in parallel to RetrieveAmount(). Please let me know if i am thinking in the rite direction or not.

Could anyone guide me of the 2nd part of the question.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is Thread.join(int millis)

Comment: "I can use the executors with fixed thread pool of number of threads as 2 and..."  If you have an ExecutorService that is intended for running background tasks, you just use it and don't worry about how many threads it has.  That's the whole point of ExecutorService:  It decouples the code responsible for knowing how many worker threads to configure from the code that needs to use worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

1) Both RetrieveFromSystem1(user) and RetrieveFromSystem2(user) can have there own threads started in the body of the methods. And there is no restriction on these two to be synchronized, it should work.
2) The thread class should have code like

---

long  startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); while(true) { if( System.currentTimeMillis - startTime < 10000) psudeocode: getData(); else Thread.currentThread().interrupt()};

---

In its run()

Comment: How does it help to have RetriveFromSystemN(...) create its own thread if it doesn't return until the result has been retrieved?  I'd have thought that the point of using threads was to overlap the two retrievals.